# NetBeans documentation TeX

Tags: netbeans, tex

I wondered if there was a way to integrate TeX with NetBeans?

I've tried google it and couldn't find a clear answer, but found an Eclipse project doing it but need it for NetBeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/5749/tex-language-support ? I know this plugin is old but perhaps it fits to your needs?